# scala play! page only for new users

Tags: security, scala, playframework-2.0

I want to have my registration page available only when visitor is **not logged in**.

I'd like to accomplish that with `Security.Authenticated` method. How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the Secured trait, maybe define your own Action type? This is untested...

```
def NotLoggedInAction(f: Request[AnyContent] => Result): Action[AnyContent] = {
    Action { request =>
      if(isLoggedIn(request)) Redirect(views.html.noneForYou)
      else f(request)
    }
}

def isLoggedIn(request: Request) = ??? // You implement this

def mustBeSecured = NotLoggedInAction { implicit request =>
   // Your application logic here.
}
```

Comment: I thought that using Secured for authentication will be more safe, but your proposition is also good :)